# Unity - How to change AnimationClip KeyFrame values at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

is it possible to change keyframe values from a clip at runtime via script in Unity3d? (non-legacy)

I want to change the value of the "Body > arm" - rotation.z. There are 3 keyframes at the normal clip and i want to change the only the 2nd keyframe value to maybe 120f.

At the Screenshot below you can see my "RightArm" Property (first keyframe value is 0). The result have to be, when i rise my mouse (position.y is maybe also 120), the arm has to follow while hes in this animationclip.

I hope i descriped my problem enough, that you can understand it. Every google solution and many code examples doesnt work...

Thanks!

My Unity Version: 2019.2.8

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AnimationClip.SetCurve(string relativePath, Type type, string propertyName, AnimationCurve curve)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SetCurve.html)

where

> **relativePath**
>   
>  Path to the game object this curve applies to. The `relativePath` is formatted similar to a pathname, e.g. `"root/spine/leftArm"`. If `relativePath` is empty it refers to the `GameObject` the `Animation`/`Animator` component is attached to.

In your case probably something like `"Body/RightShoulder/RightArm"`

> **type**
>   
>  The class type of the component that is animated.

In your case `typeof(Transform)`

> **propertyName**
>   
>  The name or path to the property being animated.

Note that for Unity built-in components the names of the properties sometimes differ from what is displayed in the Inspector! Always refer to the API.

in your case `localRotation`

> **curve**
>   
>  The animation curve.

(Modified) Example from the documentation:

```c#
public AnimationClip clip;

private void Start()
{
    // create a curve to move the GameObject and assign to the clip
    Keyframe[] keys;
    keys = new Keyframe[3];
    keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, 0.0f);
    // within 12 seconds rotate to 120°
    keys[1] = new Keyframe(12.0f, 120f);
    // Whatever you need as 3. keyframe
    keys[2] = new Keyframe(16.0f, 0f);

    var curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
    clip.SetCurve("Body/RightShoulder/RightArm", typeof(Transform), "localRotation.z", curve);
}
```

Also see [`Keyframe`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Keyframe-ctor.html) and [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html)

---

**Note:**

Unfortunately it is not possible to **get** an existing curve (at least not trivial) so you always have to **set** one from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it and something happend but it seems like that the keyframe value (maybe 120°) are not important. My Arm always rotate round about 180° (with every keyframe cO).

My Code:

        relativePath = "RightShoulder/RightArm";
        Keyframe[] keys = new Keyframe[2];
        keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, 0.0f);
        keys[1] = new Keyframe(1.0f, 5f);

        AnimationCurve curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
        channelingClip.SetCurve(relativePath, typeof(Transform), "localRotation.z", curve);